# jquery datepicker: defining mindate and maxdate from dropdown

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this code and it's working fine. The `mindate` and `maxdate` are defined dynamically where the selected date from the dropdown will be the `maxdate` and the `mindate` will be 14 days before the `maxdate`. But when I go back to the dropdown and re-select a second time, the `mindate` and `maxdate` is locked from the first selection from the dropdown.

```html
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="12/08/2012">
    <option value="12/22/2012">
    <option value="01/05/2013">
</select>

<input type="text" id="start_date" name="xdate">

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function () {
            var bits = $(this).val().split('/');
            var end = new Date(bits[2], bits[0] - 1, bits[1]);
            var start = new Date(end.getTime());
            start.setDate(start.getDate() - 13);
            $('#start_date').multiDatesPicker({minDate:start, maxDate:end});
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can the `mindate` and `maxdate` change dynamically after selecting another range the second time? Am I missing something? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the settings for a datepicker that has already been initialized, use:

```
$('#start_date').multiDatesPicker('option', {minDate:start, maxDate:end});
```

Comment: Tried replacing the original line with you line but did not work.

Comment: Sorry, it should just be `"option"`, not `"options"`.

Comment: I tried it and is giving me this: Method option does not exist on jQuery.multiDatesPicker

Comment: It exists in standard jQuery UI datepicker, see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option. If multiDatesPicker doesn't allow it, seems like a problem with that extension.

Comment: `maxDate: "+1M 10D"` // disable dates after "in 1 months & 10 Days" see http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max